# URLconf does not appear to have any patterns in it/Circular import error

Tags: django

I am following a tutorial found in the Django documentation and upon attempting to map a view to a URL I received the following error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'pollSite.urls' d
oes not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file th
en the issue is probably caused by a circular import
```

. I have a `pollSite` project and a `poll` app.

pollSite/pollSite/urls.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('polls/', include('polls.urls')),
]
```

pollSite/poll:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world")
```

I thought I may have mistyped something so I went back and copied the code from the docs and pasted it directly into my editor and still got the same error. I'm not sure what a `circular import` is but I am also working with `virtualenv` for the first time and am not sure if that could be causing this. Any suggestions?

Tutorial incase anyone was interested: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app is called "poll", not "polls". So you have to include it by that name:

```
path('polls/', include('poll.urls')),
```

Comment: That small mistake made me start from scratch and create a new project so my app name would match for the rest of the tutorial (since it's going to hold multiple polls and not just one). Now the process of mapping a URL to a view (which seems like calling a function to me)  and the concept of each app being able to have their own URLs are both a lot more clear. I imagine I will see 'polls/1', polls/2', etc or something similar down the line in this tutorial. Thanks.